# Anchor links for accordion menu not working (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have an accordion menu on my bootstrap page, and I'm trying to include links in a text that will take the reader to an anchor on the same page, but within different tabs of the menu (so that they don't have to scroll down and click on the tabs). It only works for the first tab though. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/28/)
(sorry for the typos in the code! They weren't mine...)

And here's the code:

```
<p>Go to <a href="#Tab1">Tab1</a>.</p>
<p>Go to <a href="#Tab2">Tab2</a>.</p>
<p>Go to <a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a>.</p>

<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown">
               <div class="tab-wrap"> 
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="parrent pull-left">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-01"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Tab1</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Tab2</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="tehnical"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Tab3</a></li>                                   
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="parrent media-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">

                                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab1">
                                    <div class="media">
                                       <div class="pull-left">
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab1-1.png">
                                           <br>
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab1-2.png">
                                           <br>
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab1-3.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <a name="Tab1"></a>
                                            <h2>Tab1</h2>
                                            <p>Tab1Tab1Tab1.</p>                         
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                                    <div class="media">
                                       <div class="pull-left">
                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab2.jpg">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <a name="Tab2"></a>
                                           <h2>Tab2</h2>                                                <p>Tab2Tab2Tab2.</p>                                                                                             </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>

                                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
                                     <div class="media">
                                         <div class="pull-left">
                                             <img class="img-responsive" src="images/services/tab3.jpg">
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="media-body">
                                             <a name="Tab3"></a>
                                             <h2>Tab3</h2>
                                             <p>Tab3Tab3Tab3 </p>

                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div> <!--/.tab-content-->  
                        </div> <!--/.media-body--> 
                    </div> <!--/.media-->     
                </div><!--/.tab-wrap-->               
            </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a detailed read over Twitter Bootstrap's documentation on "Tab Methods" at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

By simply anchor linking the individual tabs will only get you to the first tab or the currently active tab since all other tab contents are hidden by nature.

The solution you are seeking would probably need your links to bind with the "tab show" method as follows,

```
$('#someTab').tab('show')
```

> This selects the given tab and shows its associated content. Any
>   other tab that was previously selected becomes unselected and its
>   associated content is hidden.

I assume you also have *bootstrap.min.js* included to ensure those methods are available.

*Edit:* **I have created a demo here for you** http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/34/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply. Yes, I do have bootstrap.min.js included.

Comment: I read the documentation, and what you're saying definitely sounds like what I'm looking for, but how do I include the js part? I mean, how do I get the link in my text (the "Go to Tab1" part) to activate that js? How do I bind the links with the "tab show" method?

Comment: I have added a demo for you in my answer above. Check it out :p

Comment: Thanks so much! That works really well. I included it in my actual menu, and now the only problem I have is that when it jumps down to my accordion menu and opens the tab, it jumps a little too far down into the text that tab displays, so that I have to scroll a little up again to start reading at the beginning. It seems to do this no matter where I place the anchor (I originally had it before the <h2> for the tabs' headers, and then I tried placing it before the whole menu, but nothing worked). Do you know how to solve this problem by any chance?

Comment: I also have to click on it twice sometimes to get it to jump down and open the tab. Why is that?

Comment: I actually fixed both problems. I had to place the anchors outside the container, and I had to use different names for them. No idea why that worked, but it did! Thanks again for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I have a new problem: I would like to do the same with an accordion menu that's on a different page than the one where I click on the link. Is that possible? What do I need to change?

Comment: I just uploaded the website (verbiadastra.com), and it doesn't work at all there. Do you have any idea why not?