# Bootstrap: Call or Select Tabs via URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with Bootstrap tabs lately.
I can't select a tab directly via URL.

example if I visit http://example.com/sample.php#medicalrecords, #medicalrecords tab will automatically selected.

Here is my sample HTML Code

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#personnal" aria-controls="personnal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personnal Info</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" aria-controls="contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact Information</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#medicalrecords" aria-controls="medicalrecords" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Medical Records</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#billingrecords" aria-controls="billingrecords" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Billing Records</a></li>                    
    </ul>

<div class="tab-content">

              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="personnal">
              Personnal akl;daks
              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="contact">
              Contact akl;daks
              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="medicalrecorpds">
              Medical Records akl;daks
              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="billingrecords">
              Billing Records akl;daks
              </div>

</div>
```

I haven't figured out a jQuery code since I'm poor at jQuery.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Edit:

I need something that automatically calls the tab via URL

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a detailed read over Twitter Bootstrap's documentation on "Tab Methods" at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

You would probably need to do the following code with your external links,

```
$('#someTab').tab('show')
```

**I have created a demo here for you** 
https://jsfiddle.net/mhzr14yu/4/

Note: You should also check out my other post here about anchor links for accordion/tab menus  at [Anchor links for accordion menu not working (Bootstrap 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397311/anchor-links-for-accordion-menu-not-working-bootstrap-3/31397532#31397532)